# How to pass array values as an object prop dynamicly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to treat array values as props of object. For example:

```
let arr = ['masa_icerik', 'urunler', 0, 'urun_adet'];
let obj = {
  "_id": "5c13bd566704aa5e372dddcf",
  "masa_id": 3,
  "masa_numara": 3,
  "masa_magaza": 1,
  "masa_icon": "kola",
  "masa_adi": "salon 3",
  "masa_durum": 1,
  "masa_icerik": {
    "adisyon": "J1554745811908",
    "urunler": [{
      "urun_adet": 14,
      "urun_fiyat": 3,
      "urun_id": "5c16686b93d7b79ae6367864",
      "urun_odenen": 0
    }, {
      "urun_adet": 1,
      "urun_fiyat": 5,
      "urun_id": "5c16686b93d7b79ae6367865",
      "urun_odenen": 0
    }]
  },
  "masa_acilis": "2019-04-08T17:50:12.052Z",
  "masa_acan": "5c1eda01d1f4773110dd6ada"
};
```

I have an array and an object like above and I want to do something like this:

```
let res;
arr.forEach(elem => {
   res = obj[elem];
});
```

and after that I need to get something like :

```
obj['masa_icerik']['urunler'][0]['urun_adet']
```

The number of the values is dynamic from server. Thats why i need something like this. Is there any way to do that? I need to change that property and return the changed obj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forEach` loop to loop thru the array and store it to a temp variable. If all elements exist, it will change the value.

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let obj = {'a':{'b':{'c':1}}};
let newValue = "NEW VALUE";

let temp = obj;
arr.forEach((o, i) => {
  if (i < arr.length - 1) temp = temp[o] || null;
  else if (temp !== null && typeof temp === "object" ) temp[o] = newValue;
});

console.log(obj);
```

---

If there are multiple multiple object properties missing in the last part of the array.

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let obj = {'a': {'b': {}}};
let newValue = "NEW VALUE";

let temp = obj;
arr.forEach((o, i) => {
  if (i < arr.length - 1) {
    if (!temp[o]) temp[o] = {[arr[i + 1]]: {}};
    temp = temp[o];
  } else if (temp !== null && typeof temp === "object") temp[o] = newValue;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I need to set that value of object. Not to get it. Sorry for misleading question.

Comment: `On side note`: you should consider undefined cases, i mean arr input like `[1,2,3]`

Comment: @Code Maniac Yes I have a value like 0 in my array

Comment: @CodeManiac, I'm about to post that code. But user don't need the first code. So don't need to post it :)

Comment: Just posted it. :)

Comment: @Eddie, I need to return the original object with changed value.

Comment: @Eddie, I update my code with my original array and object.

Comment: @İsmailFurkanGÖKHASAN, what format of object you are expecting? `"obj['masa_icerik']['urunler'][0]['urun_adet']"` will just return the new value and not the object

Comment: @Eddie, I need to update `"obj['masa_icerik']['urunler'][0]['urun_adet']"` this and then return `obj`

Comment: @İsmailFurkanGÖKHASAN That is what is going on the first code. It updates `obj` with the `newValue`,

Comment: but it won't return the whole `obj`

Comment: `forEach` does not return a new object. You can use/return `obj`.

Comment: @Eddie, Owww. I'm so sorry. I just realize that. Thank you. That's exactly what I need.

Comment: @Eddie, Sorry for bothering you but, what if the object doesn't have that properties, can we create them? This code works if object has this properties.

Comment: @İsmailFurkanGÖKHASAN Now worries. I updated the code. If there the last array element is not a property key, it will create. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `references`

Here idea is

- Initialize `val` with `object` reference
- Loop through array and keep setting new reference to `val`

```js
let arr = ['a','b','c'];
let obj = {'a':{'b':{'c':1}}};

let getMeValue = (arr) => {
  let val=obj;
  arr.forEach(e => val = val && val[e] )
  return val
}

console.log(getMeValue(arr))
console.log(getMeValue([1,2,3]))
```

> UPDATE: I want to change values

```js
let arr = ['a','b','c'];
let obj = {'a':{'b':{'c':1}}};

let getMeValue = (arr) => {
  let val = obj
  arr.forEach((e,i) => {
  if(i === arr.length-1 && val){
    val[e] = 5
   }
  else {
  val = val && val[e]
  }
 })
 return obj
}

console.log(getMeValue(arr))
```

Comment: I need to set that value of object. Not to get it. Sorry for misleading question.

Comment: @İsmailFurkanGÖKHASAN what do you mean ? you want to change the value of `object` ?

Comment: I need to change the object like `obj['a']['b]...['n'] = 'someValue';` @Code Maniac

Comment: @İsmailFurkanGÖKHASAN you can try the second snippet

Comment: I need to return the original object with changed value.

Comment: I update my code with my original array and object.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully understanding where you are getting the new values from but I think this will get you on the right track.

```
let newObj = {};

arr.map(each => {
   newObj[each] = "new value";
 })

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your requirment here, I guess you want the below:

```js
    let func = (arr, value)=>{
        r = {};
        r[arr[arr.length-1]] = value;
        for(let i = arr.length-2; i>=0; i--){
            obj = {};
            obj[arr[i]] = r;
            r = obj;
        }
        return r;
    }
    console.log(func(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1));
```